# csvの書くときのnewline＝""としなくても、段落が変わらないのはなぜか？

Tags: python, csv

以下を実行しました。(あえてwithを使わないで書きました。)

```
csv_file = open('svl1.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8")
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
new_file = open('practice.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Word', 'symbol'])
for line in csv_reader:
    csv_writer.writerow(line)
new_file.close()
csv_file.close()
```

そしてその結果をprintしたら以下でした。

```
['Word', 'symbol']
[]
['also', 'ɔ́ːlsou']
[]
['air', 'ɛ́ər']
[]
['airplane', 'ɛ́ərplèin']
[]
['airport', 'ɛ́ərpɔ̀ːrt']
[]
['album', 'ǽlbəm']
[]
['all', 'ɔ́ːl']
```

そこで調べていたら、newlineのparameterを設定しないといけないとわかりました。

```
new_file = open('practice.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='')
```

問題自体は解決した。しかし、以下の動画ではファイルを実行しているのですが、この人のoutputは空のリストがありません。

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5uM4VKywbA&t=214s
7:42～あたりです。

なぜ、newline=''としていないのに、この人は空白ができなかったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTubeの動画はMacOS(Unix系OS)だからでしょう。
[Windows で Python の csv モジュールで改行コードを正しく出力する](https://blog.sgry.jp/entry/2019/07/26/001341)

> Python 標準の csv パッケージ は CSV ファイルを手軽に入出力できるので重宝しているのだけれど、Windows で使うと改行コードがおかしくなることがあった。見た目的には「各行が 2 回改行されてしまう」ような状態。これを回避する簡単な方法がやっと分かったので、今日はその備忘録。
>
> 普通に CSV 書き出しを実装すると、テキストモードで開いたファイルオブジェクトを渡して csv.writer または csv.DictWriter を作り、その writerow() などのメソッドを呼ぶことになると思う。こうすると、残念なことに「CR+LF (\r\n) で出力されるべきところ CR+CR+LF (\r\n\n) が出力され」てしまう。多くの Windows プログラマはピンと来るだろうけれど、どうやら csv モジュールは OS を区別せず常に改行コードとして CR+LF (\r\n) を書き込んでしまっているのだと推測される。

Pythonのドキュメントの脚注にも記述されています。
[脚注  csv --- CSV ファイルの読み書き](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html#id3)

> 脚注
> 1(1,2) newline='' が指定されない場合、クォートされたフィールド内の改行は適切に解釈されず、書き込み時に \r\n を行末に用いる処理系では余分な \r が追加されてしまいます。csv モジュールは独自 ([universal](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines)) の改行処理を行うため、newline='' を指定することは常に安全です。

上記の「書き込み時に \r\n を行末に用いる処理系」というのがWindows系OSのことを指しています。

[universal newlines 用語集 Python 3.8.1](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines)

> テキストストリームの解釈法の一つで、以下のすべてを行末と認識します: Unix の行末規定 '\n'、Windows の規定 '\r\n'、古い Macintosh の規定 '\r'。利用法について詳しくは、 PEP 278 と PEP 3116 、さらに [bytes.splitlines()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.splitlines) も参照してください。

Comment: おっしゃる通りで、windowsを使っています。OSでこんなところに違いが出るなんて思ってもいなかったです。助かりました。